# nfFor from angular2 prevent update of nested tag element

Tags: angular, ngfor

I try to start with Angular 2. Use stable version 2.0.0.
I want to update sub-list of list. Each list I get from service. For this in angular2 I use ngFor for both parts.

**The problem:**
When I use ngFor for upper list, sub-list does not want to update. How this could be fixed?
When I use ngFor only for sub-list - everything is ok (I could update only sub-list).

[Link on plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Kgi4NXxp2gZeMf50bQrP/):

1. app.ts - Here upper list
2. race.component.ts - sub-list element with update button

Comment: @yurzui, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you return new array every time.

```
list():Array<any>{
  return [{name: "London"}, {name: "Paris"}];
}
```

Angular2 matches old array with new array through:

**NgFor directive** (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.2/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_for.ts#L122-L127)

```
NgFor.prototype.ngDoCheck = function () {
  if (this._differ) {
    var changes = this._differ.diff(this.ngForOf);
    if (changes) this._applyChanges(changes);
  }
};
```

The next function is fired inside the `diff` method:

```
function looseIdentical(a, b) {
  return a === b || typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && isNaN(a) && isNaN(b);
}
```

in javascript `{} === {}` will always be `false`

Hence your list will always be redrawn.

**I see two ways to solve it:**

**1)** Use `array` instead of function that returns `array`

**component**

```
list = [{name: "London"}, {name: "Paris"}];
```

**html**

```
*ngFor="let race of list"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/LtAGjWZsdOx0UU7qp0Dk?p=preview)**

**2)** To customize the default tracking algorithm `ngFor` directive through `trackBy` option:

**component**

```
trackByFn(index, race) {
  return index;
}
```

or a bit better to use unique `id`:

```
trackByFn(index, race) {
  return race.id
}
list():Array<any>{
  return [{id: 1, name: "London"}, {id: 2, name: "Paris"}];
}
```

and in html:

```
*ngFor="let race of list(); trackBy: trackByFn"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/oOF21CPOsutfNj24qbTP?p=preview)**

See more details about the `trackBy`:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngfortrackby